# Mysql locks on Freeing item: Why?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

[image: mtop]

Link to full image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VODiJ.png

my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
plugin-load=ha_xtradb.so

datadir=/w/mysql
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 100G
innodb_log_file_size = 2G
innodb_file_per_table=1
max_connections = 500
```

I'm using MariaDB. Mysql "locks down" like that (look at the basic insert query for example) after an hour of so that i run my script.

What could it be?

---

free:

```
SYSTEM MEMORY INFORMATION:
mem_wire:       17899466752 (  17070MB) [ 11%] Wired: disabled for paging out
mem_active:  +  12577095680 (  11994MB) [  8%] Active: recently referenced
mem_inactive:+    148381696 (    141MB) [  0%] Inactive: recently not referenced
mem_cache:   +       151552 (      0MB) [  0%] Cached: almost avail. for allocation
mem_free:    + 119319916544 ( 113792MB) [ 79%] Free: fully available for allocation
mem_gap_vm:  +       839680 (      0MB) [  0%] Memory gap: UNKNOWN
-------------- ------------ ----------- ------
mem_all:     = 149945851904 ( 142999MB) [100%] Total real memory managed
mem_gap_sys: +   4594712576 (   4381MB)        Memory gap: Kernel?!
-------------- ------------ -----------
mem_phys:    = 154540564480 ( 147381MB)        Total real memory available
mem_gap_hw:  +  17258127360 (  16458MB)        Memory gap: Segment Mappings?!
-------------- ------------ -----------
mem_hw:      = 171798691840 ( 163840MB)        Total real memory installed

SYSTEM MEMORY SUMMARY:
mem_used:       52330242048 (  49906MB) [ 30%] Logically used memory
mem_avail:   + 119468449792 ( 113933MB) [ 69%] Logically available memory
-------------- ------------ ----------- ------
mem_total:   = 171798691840 ( 163840MB) [100%] Logically total memory
```

uptime:

```
 2:32PM  up 6 days, 21:09, 2 users, load averages: 0.64, 0.44, 0.32 (loads during the script grows up to 20 (24 HT cores, 12 physical cores)
```

uname -a

```
 FreeBSD  8.2-RELEASE-p3 FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE-p3 #0: Tue Sep 27 18:45:57 UTC 2011     root@amd64-builder.daemonology.net:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
```

Comment: To diagnose this, we need a bit more info: free -m, uptime, uname -a

Comment: Looking at your "free" output and "innodb_buffer_pool_size = 100G" in your my.cnf, I see MariaDB taking only a fraction of what it may take. Just for the sake of diagnosis: Could you reduce innodb_buffer_pool_size to something like  60G and retry?

Comment: Yes, sure. MariaDB isn't taking all the ram it could since that the database isn't still big enough however ;)

Comment: OK, my line of thought is: I have seen memory allocation die horribly in MySQL if "too much" RAM was available. This has allways only happened with more than 64GB innodb total. Disclaimer: None of this was with MariaDB or *BSD

Comment: are the where clauses in update statements covered by indexes or each one of them locks the entire table?

Comment: Hi Darhazer, i didn't know this. If i have a where on a non-indexed field, will the query "block" the full table? Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to update on this. I disabled the query cache, setted the logs to be flushed every 2 seconds and so on - with no result at all. the problem where the high concurrency of read and writes on the table. i created another temp table where i do the reads (only a part of it, the fronted reads) and it works perfectly.